# sqlite3_exec with and without explicit transaction

Tags: c, sqlite

With the following code:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);
for (int i=0; (row=rows[i]).id != NULL; i ++) {
    if (i == 100000) break;
    asprintf(&query, "insert into Sales1M (id, date, instance_id, territory_id, code, price, currency_code_id, price_in_usd)"
                     "values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
                      row.id, row.date, row.instance_id, row.territory_id, row.code, row.price, row.currency_code_id, row.price_in_usd);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, NULL, NULL, &error_msg);
}
sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

> InsertSQL: 0.384135s to do the 100K inserts.

However, if I remove the `BEGIN TRANSACTION...`, the inserts are almost 100x slower:

> InsertSQL: 4.592789 to do the 100K inserts.

Why is this so?

Does SQLite automatically do a `BEGIN...COMMIT` as a wrapper around the `sqlite3_exec` command if there isn't a pending `TRANSACTION` already in place? Or, why does it take so long without explicitly doing the begin/commit in the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you don't do `BEGIN...COMMIT` there is an implicit one after every statement (`COMMIT` is a one-liner that turns it back to commit at end of statement).

Once having done so, you're bound by the disk write time which is going to be 10s of milliseconds per row (less if SSD but still a lot more than it can do with not committing after every row). You don't want that.

Batch your inserts. About 10,000 rows per transaction is write for typical hardware these days.